# Why can't this python function read a global variable?

Tags: python, function, variables, global

I have a main app with the lines of code:

```
global aa
aa=17
```

I then import a function to test reading global variables. I have written:

```
def test_funct():
    print(aa)
    return 0
```

in a file called 'helper_functions' and import it:

```
from helper_functions import test_funct
```

I then call this function from another function:

```
def test_tab():
    test_funct()
```

when I call test_tab(), I get the error:

NameError: name 'aa' is not defined

Why is this? I thought the definition of a global variable was one that was accessible in all functions and that you don't need to do anything special to call them in python.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Python has *module-level globals*, not "true globals" (this is usually considered a good thing). `test_func` always looks in the `globals()` of the module it was defined in.

Comment: As an aside, `return 0` worries me when I see it. Are you coming from a C background?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga on point, as always. I’ll add that you should be very careful about the design of your program, how idiomatic it is, ect.

Comment: Thanks! I think I understand the root cause of my problem now. The code I presented here was the simplest code I could reproduce the problem with. In some of the programs I'm actually trying to write I had eval and exec functions called in the nested function, which I believe count as another function. For this reason, I believe, globals declared in the outer function weren't understood by the evals in the inner function. Thanks for shedding some light on this.